# Angular.js: How to Append Hash Fragment after clicking element and making this shareable

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, fragment-identifier

Apologies for the somewhat basic question.

On an Angular single page application, I'm trying to create a fragment identifier after clicking on an element and changing its CSS `display` attribute from `display:none` to `display:inline`. For instance, I'd like the URL to originally be something like:

`www.example.com/about/`

...and then after the element is clicked and displayed, the URL changes to:

`www.example.com/about/hello`

or

`www.example.com/about/#hello`

...and upon sharing the new link, I'd like that clickable element to automatically be set to `display: inline`.

I'm using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). Would something like this be achievable with nested views? Or ui-sref? I'm not too sure what I should be researching or what direction to go in for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't use `display:none` with angular if you can avoid it; use `ng-show` / `ng-hide` or `ng-if` instead.

Comment: Okay, good to know. Thank you.